# Ubuntu 12.04 high io by root process

Tags: ubuntu, io

Ubuntu server 12.04. Installed on hdd disk. There is postgresql database on server runing on other ssd disk.

The problem is in high io by some root process on hdd disk.

iotop shows 2 processes with high io:

```
13:29:52   335 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % [kworker/u256:1]
13:29:40   775 be/4 root      441.07 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 96.85 % find . -depth -xdev ! -name . ! ( -path ./lost+found -uid 0 ) ! ( -path ./quota.user -uid 0 ) ! ( -path ./aquota.user -uid 0 ) ! ( -path ./quota.group -uid 0 ) ! ( -path ./aquota.group -uid 0 ) ! ( -path ./.journal -uid 0 ) ! ( -path ./.clean -uid 0 ) ! ( -path "./...security*" -uid 0 ) ! -type d -delete
```

This process runing about half hour.

What does it mean?

The problem was solved by itself. I think it was some os background process.

Comment: I hope you have backups, because that means someone is deleting all your files. And it's quite likely the system has been compromised.

Comment: I have cheked openssh sessions. It was only my connection

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if something is performing a clean up of some sort.

Use `lsof` to determine where that find command is running:

```
lsof -P -n -p 775 | grep cwd
```

Or just check /proc:

```
ls -ld  /proc/775/cwd
```

That might help identify what called that process.